# Android Custom Navigation Drawer with specific design

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-appbarlayout

I am new to Android. I want to implement navigation drawer as this : [image]

The Navigation drawer should open below App Bar and should have red left pane for category icon and right page (white) with navigation options.

I am trying to convert default Navigation Drawer activity of Android to this style but don't know where to start with.

If anyone can help me implementing this would be great help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you need a custom navigation drawer to achive that, you can start by following this link https://github.com/awidiyadew/DrawerMultiLevelListview